# Should I include third-party (Devexpress) dll files inside my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The way I am going to do is create a `SolutionItems` directory inside my solution and physically copy all referenced third-party dll files into that folder, then I change reference to that `local copy` inside the `SolutionItems` directory. But the question is: does it worth the trouble of manage it manually?

I would think it is a good idea as it is dependency for my application. Without including the dll file, the whole solution wouldn't be able to run inside Visual Studio if the machine don't have the required DevExpress version installed. My `Deployment Project` will handle dependency correctly regardless, as far as the reference been setup properly.

On the other hand, because DevExpress will normally automatically add references, and I can using `Project converter` to update version of DevExpress. So without reference to the `Local Copy` inside solution, it is pretty much working out of the box whenever I am changing reference, or change between DevExpress versions. If instead, I am managing my `local copy`, I am create more work for myself to maintain the reference and physical copy of dll files. Should I keep it simple as it is now, base on the assumptions that whoever working with this application will need have a copy of DevExpress installed?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825/best-practice-for-releasing-microsoft-dlls-in-setup) previous discussion


  [1]:

Comment: @tbroberg, thanks, but my question is about development, as my installer will copy the dependency dll files, not about install or redistribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem where I work.  5 devs, 1 svn and mulitple copies of DevExpress dlls floating around.  We tried at first maintaining a local copy (updated manually) as you describe, this did **not** work well for us.  So yes, the easiest thing to do (in my experience) is require everyone who works on the project have a copy of DevExpress installed.

Comment: Thank you for share your experience. I suppose because the way DevExpress components reference dll files, it is much more work to manage the dll files menually, rather than that, I will let DevExpress manage them. The provtential downside, well when we see the need for including the dll files in the source tree, then we will deal with that.