# ReportViewer - System.IO.FileNotFoundException on Windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I have got ReportViewer in my project and when I install the app on Windows XP it says this when I try to do report with ReportViewer: System.IO.FileNotFoundException on Windows XP

> ```
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms,
> Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies.
> The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
> ```

When I install this app on my laptop with Windows 8 everything is working fine.
How can I fix this issue? I tried to search through the internet but found nothing helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you right click on the reference to that dll, and hit properties, is `Copy Local` set to `True`?  If not, that's the first thing to try

Comment: @Jonesy Thanks for comment. I tried to do what you proposed but couldnt find any reference to dll. You mean in visual studio sulution right click my report?

Comment: In the solution explorer, in your project, in the references folder, that .dll should be in there, right click that

Comment: @Jonesy I tried that but still got the same Exception

Comment: @Jonesy I think this is what I need http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You are right with the Report Viewer redistributable, but you need another version. One of these two should do the trick:

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27230) - this is the one that I used, if I remember correctly.

[MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747)

Also note that there may be some other requirements that will be prompted for by the Report Viewer 2012 installation. You can find these also on the internet, for example [MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) also requires (download page -> Additional information):

> Pre-requisites Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or higher
>   for server processing mode. NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or .NET Framework
>   4.0 The SQL Server System CLR Types package

**EDIT**

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/962debcf-1a9e-4cf2-8e4b-5d1f4d85be60/report-viewer-2012-on-windows-xp) on MSDN and the information on the Report Viewer redistributables, they cannot be used on Windows XP. 

I heard you can overcome this problem if you take the required dlls (including SQLSysClrTypes) and add them to the project and reference them in the project. Also make sure that Copy Local is set to True.

I don't know if this affects the terms of use for the Report Viewer dlls (are they redistributable outside the ReportViewer package?).

**EDIT 2**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825/best-practice-for-releasing-microsoft-dlls-in-setup/17833#17833) you have to check the EULA for the respective redistributable package. I think further inquiry is required for certainty.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your help, at the moment I was trying to install both on Windows XP but Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP said that it is missing SQLSysClrTypes_msi and led me to this website to download it:
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217024 But unfortunately it was unable to download? The other Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime cannot be opened on XP when I double click the msi nothing opens. Would you please help me solve this out ?

Comment: I tried to add to reference SQLSysClrTypes but could found it in project reference? MAy you help me?

Comment: @Marek You have to install the Report Viewer Redistributable 2012 on a Windows 7 machine and copy the dll from the GAC and reference it into your project.

Comment: I have installed them on other machine (Windows 8) and got the same error so I installed the ReportViewer Redistributables 2012 and everything worke fine. Im having problems with installation on Windows XP. Because I can't install there SQLSysClrTypesx86 as I'm using Sql Server 2012. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: You need SqlServer 2012 locally to run your application?

Comment: No I don`t need. I connect to Sql Server 2012 remotely via this application. I`m not sure if you exactly understood my problem. I have app that I try to install on XP and I got this error. This app fills the ReportViewer from Sql Server 2012.

Comment: ReportViewer does only require those SQLSysClrTypes, which are in a dll. This dll is found in the GAC after installing ReportViewer on a machine. So, go to your Windows 8 machine, go into GAC folder and copy the dll. Attach it to your project and reference it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me I solved this issue via adding to Redistributables Report Viewer 2010. ReportViewer loads correctly but the Report got another error. If you are interested pleas check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415691/reportviewer-error-the-definition-of-the-report-is-invalid