# ReportViewer error - The definition of the report " is invalid. Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectMode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reportviewer

I have ReportViewer in my project. When I create .exe of this file in InstallShield in Vsual Studio 2012 I add into `Redistributables Microsoft ReportViewer 2010`.

When I do install my app on Windows 8 - every ReportViewer displays it's report correctly.

I'm having problem on `Windows XP` the ReportViewer loads correctly but displayes this error instead of correct Report:

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the report " is invalid. An unexpected error ocurred in Report
>   Processing.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectMode. Version =11.0.0.,
>   Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=89845dc8080cc91 or one of its
>   dependencies. this system cannot find the file specified.

I ensure you that in `references I have added Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winfroms 11.0.0.0` and `Copy Local = true`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out that this error means that you are missing `Microsoft.ReportViewer.PorcessingObjectMode.dll` `version 11.0.0.0`. There is one solution:

On your `Windows 8` Machine do following:

1. Open dos command prompt (press START + R then type cmd and press ENTER)
2. Type `cd ..` until you are on `C:\ >` Type `Cd windows\assembly\gac_msil\Microsoft.ReportViewer.pro*` and press enter
3. Just type `cd 11*`
4. Then type `copy * c:\`
5. The `.dll` will be copied to your `C` directory.
6. This file simply copy into your `Program Files` on `Windows XP machine` to folder where your application has been installed.

Hope it helps to others as I was stuct with this issue for long time.

Answer (score 16):

I upvoted the reply marked as the answer because I was, infact, missing .dlls - but I did not fix it in the manner @Marek suggested. I'm using VS2013 and installing the Microsoft.Reporting nuget package fixed the problem. I would suggest to anyone with this problem trying this. That way, you automatically get all the dependencies.

[image]

Comment: Dude, this is exactly what I needed to know. You cannot believe how much time this saved me for figuring out how to do it the "right" way, and I was pulling out my hair yesterday with half assed answers and other nonsense that just didn't work... But this... This is the key to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Nuget is the best (for most things...)!

Answer (score 2):

Marek's answer is great and helped me, I just wanted to add an additional file that mine needed. In addition to

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
```

I also needed

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

(I'm running this from a server that *has SQLServer but not Reporting Services* so perhaps that's why the 2nd file was missing.)

As Marek pointed out, you need to copy the file using the command prompt because the DLLs in GAC_MSIL are hidden from Windows Explorer, so you won't see them if you search for them using Explorer.
I was stumped because I'm generating a PDF with a daily task, so all I kept seeing in my log file was the cryptic error `"An error occurred during local report processing."` I never saw the ReportViewer's face, which at least tells you the missing file.

To troubleshoot this, I created a quickie test program and displayed the ReportViewer, which made it more clear which DLLs I needed:
[image]

Comment: In my **development machine** is **working**. In **stagging environment**, I get the error `Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`. How can I get or download a single ***Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll*** or **minimal redistributable** for a _server Windows 2008R2_ ?

Comment: How is your **quickie test program** ? _source code available_?

Comment: Kiquenet, I will see if I can find the test program, I might've deleted it; I'll let you know. I think all I did was drag a report viewer onto a form and ran that program on my server, so I could see what files the server was missing. In my case I was able to get the file Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll from my workstation and copied it to the server. I'm not sure how my workstation got the file--maybe Visual Studio installed it?

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning

It is necessary for installing **nuget** packages of **'Microsoft.Report.Viewer'** , **'ReportViewer.WebForms'** , **'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms'** and also **'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewer.WebForms/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Report.Viewer/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

Then it should be check web.config for some tags

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        </buildProviders>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false" />
```

```
    <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```